# ModelState refresh in post to remove errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Problem:  ModelState is not valid, complaining that there is no Event.

I've tried associating it and done a TryUpdateModel

Inspecting raceViewModel it does look fine.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(RaceViewModel raceViewModel, Guid idEvent)
    {
        Event _event = uow.Events.Single(e => e.Id == idEvent);
        raceViewModel.RaceInVM.EventU = _event;
        TryUpdateModel<RaceViewModel>(raceViewModel);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            SetupDropDownsStronglyTyped(raceViewModel);
            return View(raceViewModel);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your `idEvent` parameter may not be what you expect it to be. The `uow.Events.Single` call then fails and throws an exception (there is no `Event` with the provided `Id`).

Comment: many thanks.. this wasn't it.  However solved it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826555/how-to-get-rid-of-dropdownlistfor-mvc3